# Is union available in LINQ query syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I noticed that I was unable to structure a linq query with a `union` of two selects, using [ANSI syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

The .net documentation has an article on [query syntax examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/query-expression-examples-linq-to-dataset) where union is not shown. However, under [.net examples for method syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/method-based-query-examples-linq-to-dataset), a union example is given.

I know I can combine query syntax selects and Method based selects to bypass this problem, but I am curious if I can do entirely without method based syntax.

```
var strings =
          from MemberInfo member in Whitelist.Members
          select member.ToString()
          union
          from Type type in Whitelist.Types
          select type.ToString();
```

Comment: [Given this list of keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/query-keywords) for LINQ's query syntax it looks like you're going to have to do a union with the method syntax.

Comment: Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/return-the-set-union-of-two-sequences I think it is safe to assume it isn't possible.

Comment: LINQ and ANSI queries only have passing similarities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no. As much as you can do in query syntax, it lacks some basic operations (as you have seen). You will have to use the extension methods.

Given

[Query Keywords (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/query-keywords)

---

[Enumerable.Union Method (IEnumerable, IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Produces the set union of two sequences by using the default equality
>   comparer.

**Example**

```
ProductA[] store1 = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new ProductA { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

ProductA[] store2 = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new ProductA { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };

var union = store1.Union(store2);
```

or

```
var union =
     (from MemberInfo member in Whitelist.Members select member.ToString()).Union
     (from Type type in Whitelist.Types select type.ToString());
```

or equivalent

```
var union =
    (from MemberInfo member in Whitelist.Members select member.ToString()).Concat
    (from Type type in Whitelist.Types select type.ToString()).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 4):

LINQ and ANSI queries only have passing similarities. There should be very little expectation that any of the ANSI syntax crosses over to LINQ.

`UNION` is no exception.

Here are my three preferred options:

(1)

```
var strings =
    Enumerable
        .Union(
            from MemberInfo member in Whitelist.Members
            select member.ToString(),
            from Type type in Whitelist.Types
            select type.ToString());
```

(2)

```
var members =
    from MemberInfo member in Whitelist.Members
    select member.ToString();

var types =
    from Type type in Whitelist.Types
    select type.ToString()

var strings = Enumerable.Union(members, types);
```

(3)

```
var strings =
    (
            from MemberInfo member in Whitelist.Members
            select member.ToString()
    ).Union(
            from Type type in Whitelist.Types
            select type.ToString()
    );
```

I like these options as they help to clearly show that a `Union` is being performed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Union` method. Like that.

```
var strings = (from MemberInfo member in Whitelist.Members
          select member.ToString())
          .Union(
          from Type type in Whitelist.Types
          select type.ToString());
```